# mc-wrapper does not exit to MC_PWD directory

Tags: linux, bash, shell, midnight-commander

I recently installed openSUSE 13.1 and set up the `mc` in typical why by aliasing mc with `mc-wrapper.sh` to have it exit into the last working directory in `mc` instance. However this does not seem to be working. I tried to debug the `mc-wrapper.sh` script - the `echo` commands.

```
MC_USER=`id | sed 's/[^(]*(//;s/).*//'`
MC_PWD_FILE="${TMPDIR-/tmp}/mc-$MC_USER/mc.pwd.$$"
/usr/bin/mc -P "$MC_PWD_FILE" "$@"

if test -r "$MC_PWD_FILE"; then
        MC_PWD="`cat "$MC_PWD_FILE"`"
        if test -n "$MC_PWD" && test -d "$MC_PWD"; then
                echo "will cd in : $MC_PWD"
                cd $MC_PWD
                echo $(pwd)
        fi
        unset MC_PWD
fi

rm -f "$MC_PWD_FILE"
unset MC_PWD_FILE
echo $(pwd)
```

To my surprise, `mc-wrapper-sh` does change the directory and is in the directory before exiting but back in bash prompt the working directory is the one from which the script was invoked.

Can it be that some bash settings is required for this to work?

Comment: Your script runs as new process with its own environment and can not change the environment of the calling shell. You can only change working directory of your shell if you source your script: `source name_of_your_script`.

Comment: @Cyrus Please provide this as an answer, as this solved the same problem for me.

Answer (score 2):

Using answer above working solution for bash shell is this:

```
alias mc='source /usr/lib/mc/mc-wrapper.sh'
```

OR

```
alias mc='. /usr/lib/mc/mc-wrapper.sh'
```

Comment: works :-) wonder whether F1 in mc also tells us this?